# Can I combine .toolBar from SwiftUI and navigationBar from UINavigationController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have SwiftUI views which are wrapped in UINavigationController. This specific view has an image which covers top safearea, but when wrapping is applied, there is padding on the top where image should also be stretched. The question is - Can I override or combine navigationBar from UINavController with .toolBar from my SwiftUI view?[image]